# PHP: Summerize arrays to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that stores chapters, questions and answers. As you can see in the example this is not very convenient.
What I want to have is a multidimensional array.

What's the best practice to do this in PHP?

What I have:

```
array(
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 2'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 2',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 2',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 2',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 2'
    )
);
```

What I want to have:

```
array(
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'questions' => array(
            array(
                'text' => 'Question 1',
                'answers' => array(
                    'Answer 1',
                    'Answer 2'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'text' => 'Question 2',
                'answers' => array(
                    'Answer 1'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 2',
        'questions' => array(
            array(
                'text' => 'Question 1',
                'answers' => array(
                    'Answer 1',
                    'Answer 2'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Asking about _Best Practice_ does not hide the fact that you have not posted any code. Have you tried to code anything to achieve your specification? If so, please post it in your question

Comment: no i did not. I actually don't have any idea where to start and think that there is some one out there who had this problem already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would use some mix of array_reduce, array_map and array_values:

```
<?php

$input = array(
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 2'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 1',
        'question' => 'Question 2',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 2',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 1'
    ),
    array(
        'chapter' => 'Chapter 2',
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'answer' => 'Answer 2'
    )
);

$result = array_reduce(
  $input,
  function($output, $inputElem) {
    $output[$inputElem['chapter']]['chapter'] = $inputElem['chapter'];
    $output[$inputElem['chapter']]['questions'][$inputElem['question']]['text'] = $inputElem['question'];
    $output[$inputElem['chapter']]['questions'][$inputElem['question']]['answers'][] = $inputElem['answer'];
    return $output;
  },
  []
);

/* So now $result looks like this:
array(
  "Chapter 1"=> array(
    "chapter"=> "Chapter 1"
    "questions"=> array(
      "Question 1"=> array(
        "text"=> "Question 1"
        "answers"=> array(
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2"
        )
      )
      "Question 2"=> array(
        "text"=> "Question 2"
        "answers"=> array(
          "Answer 1"
        )
      )
    )
  )
  "Chapter 2"=> array(
    "chapter"=> "Chapter 2"
    "questions"=> array(
      "Question 1"=> array(
        "text"=> "Question 1"
        "answers"=> array(
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
*/

//we need to remove redundant keys now
$result = array_values( //removes main "chapter" keys
  array_map(
    function($chapter) {
      $chapter['questions'] = array_values($chapter['questions']); //removes "question" keys
      return $chapter;
    },
    $result
  )
);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: that looks pretty much like what I wanted. Thanks!